# Add Prefix name in a file in Perl Script

Tags: perl, rename

I am trying to write a perl script to add the prefix name on the file (~100 files), but i am failed to get it done.

Example case that what I means:

```
abc.jpg change to NYear_abc.jpg     
def.jpg change to NYear_def.jpg    
ghi.jpg change to NYear_ghi.jpg
```

This is what I try to search around and write it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
for (filename in "*".jpg;)
do {rename "$filename" "prefix_$filename";}
```

It shows me missing operator, anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about perl syntax and perl scripting but I can help you to rename all .jpg files with its `rename` command as following:

First you have to switch the directory that you have all .jpg there. for example if files are stored in `/home/star1017/jpg-file`, I type like this:

```
cd /home/star1017/jpg-file
```

then run

```
rename -n 's/(.*)\.jpg$/prefix_$1.jpg/' *.jpg
```

Match everything `(.*)` which is ends`$` with `.jpg` then add a `prefix_` and print matched group`$1`(this means print the matched group by using its back-reference) and then print the extension. Command runs for all `*.jpg` files.

Test:

```
file01.jpg renamed as prefix_file01.jpg
file02.jpg renamed as prefix_file02.jpg
file03.jpg renamed as prefix_file03.jpg
file04.jpg renamed as prefix_file04.jpg
file05.jpg renamed as prefix_file05.jpg
```

Or if you don't want to switch to that directory, run this:

```
rename -n 's/(.*)\/(.*)\.jpg$/$1\/prefix_$2.jpg/' /home/star1017/jpg-file/*.jpg
```

at the end, if you ensure the test, remove `-n` option to real rename on actual files.

Comment: sorry, are you means i just type your command directly at my xterm?
or edit it at my perl script there?

Comment: @star1017 Yes just type the command in xterm terminal and hit enter. Note that you have to change `/path/to/your/*.jpg` to your directory which all .jpg files are there.

Comment: i still no manage to change it :( do you mind snapshot and show me yours history or step how to make it? thanks a lot.

Comment: @star1017 updated answer. check please.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted a perl script, here is your Perl script **;)**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach $_ (@ARGV) {
   rename($_, "NYear_$_");
}
```

Assuming, the name of the script is `foo`, start with

```
./foo *.jpg
```

---

*Example*

```
% ls *.jpg
abc.jpg  def.jpg  ghi.jpg

% ./foo *.jpg

% ls *.jpg   
NYear_abc.jpg  NYear_def.jpg  NYear_ghi.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

then of course, there's the idiomatic perl one-liner:

```
$ ls *jpg
abc.jpg  def.jpg  ghi.jpg
$ perl -e 'rename($_, "NYear_$_") foreach @ARGV' *jpg
$ ls *.jpg   
NYear_abc.jpg  NYear_def.jpg  NYear_ghi.jpg
```